# How can I access the data inside this function? I believe it is a promise, but I'm not sure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jsx

I'd like to get the data from doc.data and pass it to another component based on which dropdown but i click on. I believe the data is in a promise format but I tried async and wait and am still having issues accessing this data. Please could someone assist with how to access this data and how I may pass it to another component. Thanks

```
async function LChallenge() {
const db = firebase.firestore();
  var data;
  function load(){
    db.collection("challenge_grids").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    data = doc.data();
    return data
   });
   });
  }
let result = await load();
console.log(result)
}


function LoadChallenge() {

LChallenge()
function display_load(){
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

  return (
    <div class="Toggle-game-state">
    <button class="dropbtn" onClick={() => display_load()} >
      Load Challenge
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <button class="myButton" >Challenge 1</button>
    <button class="myButton" >Challenge 2</button>
    <button class="myButton" >Challenge 3</button>
    </div>
    </button>
  </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `load` function doesn't return anything. Try adding `return` before `db.collection("challenge_grids")`, update `querySnapShot.forEach` into `return querySnapshot.map`

```js
async function LChallenge() {
const db = firebase.firestore();
  var data;
  function load(){
    return db.collection("challenge_grids").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      return querySnapshot.map(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        data = doc.data();
        return data;
     });
   });
  }
let result = await load();
console.log(result)
}
```

Also since LChallenge is `async` function, I guess your function can be simplified further:

```js
async function LChallenge() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("challenge_grids").get();
    const result = querySnapshot.map(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        return doc.data();
    });
    console.log(result)
}
```

To pass the data to another component, you'd need to save the `result` into a state of your `LoadChallenge` component.

Also you'd need to avoid calling API in every render, so your `LChallenge` function should not be called directly in `render`. In this example it should be in your `display_load` function

```js
function LoadChallenge() {
    const [apiResult, setApiResult] = React.useState(null);

    async function LChallenge() {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const querySnapshot = await db.collection("challenge_grids").get();
        const result = querySnapshot.map(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            return doc.data();
        });
        console.log(result)
        setApiResult(result);
    }

    function display_load() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        LChallenge()
    }

    return (
        <div class="Toggle-game-state">
            <button class="dropbtn" onClick={() => display_load()} >
                Load Challenge
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <button class="myButton" >Challenge 1</button>
                    <button class="myButton" >Challenge 2</button>
                    <button class="myButton" >Challenge 3</button>
                </div>
            </button>
            {!!apiResult && (
                <SomeComponent data={apiResult} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Nitpick: you should avoid directly manipulate the DOM in this line: `document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show")`

Instead try having another state in your Component to decide whether the `show` class is attached to your button or not.

Comment: Thank you, but the console.log(result) still returns an undefined value. Please let me know if you have any insights. Am still looking into this.

Comment: It also missed out the inner `querySnapshot.forEach`. Could you try change it into `return querySnapshot.map` instead? (See updated answer)